# Saving different plots' data presented in show

Tags: plotting, save

I have shown several plots by Show function:

```
Show[p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, PlotRange -> All]
```

I need to save data of all plots in one `txt` format, so that they can be recognizable from each other. How can I do that?

Each plot is a 2D plot say, $f_i$ as a function of $x$.

Comment: How can you save even *one* plot in a "txt" format?  Do you mean the source code that generated it?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork `ExportString[Plot3D[x y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 3, MaxRecursion -> 0, Mesh -> None], "Text"]`? What I don't understand is the goal, "recognizable from each other." @Wat, do you mean when you read the text file, you want to be able to recognize which primitives belong to which plot?  Or is another program reading the text file?  Why not export a list `{p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8}` instead of combining them with `Show`?

Answer (score 1):

```
   f[x_] := Sin[x]
    g[x_] := Cos[x]
    h[x_] := Sin[x^2]
   p1 = Plot[f[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Sin[x]"}, Above]];
    p2 = Plot[g[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Cos[x]"}, Above]];
   p3 = Plot[h[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Green, 
     PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Sin[x^2]"}, Above]];
    plotz = Show[p1, p2, p3]

       Now you can export and import your  plot by given below code(by   putting        youe file address.
    multidat = Cases[First@plotz, Line[data_] :> data, -4];
    Export["C:\\Users\\g.verma\\Documents\\outputw_" <> 
   IntegerString[#2] <> ".txt", #, "Table"] &~MapIndexed~multidat;
    ddf = Table[
    Import["C:\\Users\\g.verma\\Documents\\outputw_" <> ToString[i] <> 
   ".txt", "Table"], {i, 3}];
     ListLinePlot[{ddf[[1]], ddf[[2]], ddf[[3]]}, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green}, Frame -> True, 
     PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Sin[x]", "Cos[x]", "Sin[x^2]"}, Above]]
```

[image: exported image]

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Gopal Vermas solution:

```
p1 = ListPlot[Table[{n, n^2}, {n, 1, 10}]];
p1data = Cases[p1, Point[pts__] :> pts, Infinity];

p2 = ListLinePlot[Table[{n, 2*n}, {n, 1, 10}]];
p2data = Cases[p2, Line[pts__] :> pts, Infinity];

output = Transpose[{p1data[[1, All, 1]], p1data[[1, All, 2]], p2data[[1, All, 2]]}];

Export[StringJoin[$UserBaseDirectory, "\\output.txt"], output, "Table", 
  "FieldSeparators" -> " "] 

1. 1. 2.
2. 4. 4.
3. 9. 6.
4. 16. 8.
5. 25. 10.
6. 36. 12.
7. 49. 14.
8. 64. 16.
9. 81. 18.
10. 100. 20.
```